# Need a find function to search one column of one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need a find function to search in Column B of my worksheet titled "Quote Sheet" to find "Profit Adjustment" and it would be nice if it was case sensitive. Below is the code I am working with but I can't get the range or the wording correct. Any help is appreciated.

```
Dim rFound As Range
Set rFound = Range("B10:B1000")

    Cells.Find(What:="Profit Adjustment", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas,         LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Activate
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

I would re-write your example like this:

```
Sub copy_paste_example()
    Dim c As Range
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Quote Sheet")
        Set c = .Columns("B").Find(What:="Profit Adjustment", _
                                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        On Error GoTo NotFoundErr:
            c.Offset(0, 8).Value = c.Value
    End With
    Exit Sub
NotFoundErr:
    Debug.Print "value not found"
End Sub
```

Notes:

1. You weren't ever using the `rfound` Range Object so I removed it.
2. `Activate` and `Select` are not needed, and may even slow down your code.
3. Remember that `Find` returns a Range Object which can be useful later on in your code.

Comment: FYI - if "Profit Adjustment" isn't found, this will throw an exception because `c` will not be set, but it's being used by `c.Value`. Can I suggest using a conditional statement here? `If Not c Is Nothing Then ... End If`

Comment: That's real good stuff there, Sam. I have updated my sample code taking into account your astute observation.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub samPle()

    Dim rFound As Range, cellToFind As Range
    Set rFound = Sheets("Quote Sheet").Range("B10:B1000")

    Set cellToFind = Cells.Find(What:="Profit Adjustment", MatchCase:=True)

    If Not cellToFind Is Nothing Then
        cellToFind.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Copy ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't immediately clear to me whether you only want to find the first occurrence of `Profit Adjustment`, or if you care about **all** occurrences. If you want to find **all** rows in `Column B` that contain `Profit Adjustment`, the below Macro will work as-is. If you want to find only the **first occurrence**, then simply uncomment the line that says `Exit For`.

**Here's the code:**

```
Sub FindValueInColumn()
    Dim rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer, columnToSearch As Integer
    Dim searchString As String
    Dim quoteSheet As Worksheet
    Set quoteSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Quote Sheet")
    searchString = "Profit Adjustment"  'string to look for
    columnToSearch = 2                  '2 represents column B

    rowCount = quoteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, columnToSearch).End(xlUp).Row
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        If Not Cells(currentRow, columnToSearch).Find(What:=searchString, MatchCase:=True) Is Nothing Then
            Cells(currentRow, 8).Value = Cells(currentRow, columnToSearch).Value
            'uncomment the below "Exit For" line if you only care about the first occurrence
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Before search:**
[image]

**After search:**

[image]